# Convex/concave points of a differentiable function

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, convex-analysis

I am wondering about the following question: A strictly convex (concave) differentiable function $f:\mathcal{R}\to\mathcal{R}$ has the geometrical property that its graph lies completely above (below) the tangential line at any point (except at the point of contact). Now, this is a special property of such functions but is a relaxed version of this also valid for all (not necessarily continuously) differentiable functions? More specifically, let's call $x_0$ a *convex* point if there is a neighborhood of $x_0$ such that
$$f(x) > f(x_0) + f'(x_0)(x- x_0)$$
for all $x$ in that neighborhood. Similarly, let's call $x_0$ concave if the reverse inequality holds for some neighborhood:
$$f(x) < f(x_0) + f'(x_0)(x- x_0)$$
Then, is it true that any non-linear differentiable function has at least one concave or convex point?

Full disclosure: this question was first stated as true on a different forum without any additional information or explanations. It is possible this is well-known and I have never come across this result, or that this is completely wrong. Regardless, I am hoping to get some additional information as I think this is quite a neat result either way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $f$ be non linear in the interval $[-1,1]$. We can suppose $f(-1)=f(1)=0$ and $f(x)>0$ for some $x\in(-1,1)$. Now let $N$ be so big that the closed ball of center $(0,-N)$ and with radius $\sqrt{N^2+1}$ doesn't contain the whole graph of $f$. Let $(x_0,f(x_0))$ be one of the points of the graph furthest from $(0,-N)$. Then $f$ is concave at $x_0$.

Indeed, the whole graph of $f$ is contained in the ball of center $(0,-N)$ and boundary passing through $(x_0,f(x_0))$. This implies that the derivative of $f$ at $x_0$ has to be the slope of the tangent to that ball at $(x_0,f(x_0))$, and that tangent only intersects the graph of $f$ at $(x_0,f(x_0))$ (in fact it only intersects the ball at that one point).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I am not sure this argument holds if $x_0 = 1$. Could you please elaborate more. Thank you.

Comment: $x_0$ cannot be $1$ due to the definition of $N$: the point $(0,1)$ is at distance exactly $\sqrt{N^2+1}$ of $(0,-N)$ and there are points of the graph of $f$ further from $(0,-N)$.

Comment: Oops typo, I mean $(1,0)$ instead of $(0,1)$ in the comment above

Comment: I understand now, thank you. However, I don't believe your argument holds because of the requirements of the question of strict convexity and the fact that $x_0$ might not be unique. For example, consider a function's graph that is increasing up to $(-\epsilon, 1)$, constant to $(\epsilon, 1)$, and then decreasing. Then, $x_0=\pm\epsilon$ but the function is not strictly convex there.

Comment: Your function doesn't work because if $f$ is differentiable and constant from $-\varepsilon$ to $\varepsilon$, the furthest points cannot have $x$-coordinate between $-\varepsilon$ and $\varepsilon$. I'll add more details

Comment: If you are interested in a proof just using tangent lines instead of circumferences, you can look at my original answer before the first edit, but it is much easier using circumferences because then you don't care about the uniqueness of $x_0$ if you use a circumference

Comment: Thanks, this is great!